# Replaying actions in Redux

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-framework, redux-thunk

I'm building an library with Redux that involves using a timer. I have an action creator that dispatches a `START_TIMER` event and should also should also call `start` on a timer object. The code looks like this:

```js
// thunk action creator
const startTimer = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  
  if (!getState().timer.isRunning)
    externalTimerObject.start()

  dispatch({
    type: 'START_TIMER'
  })
  
}
```

There are two issues I'm trying to solve:

1. If I want to log my actions to a database or localStorage so that I can replay them to get to a consistent app state then even if `rootState.timer.isRunning` is true, my timer object will not be running.
2. The conditional `if (!getState().timer.isRunning)` requires that I know where in the root state `timer` is mounted. Since I'm building this as a library, I can't assume that `timer` is always going to be mounted directly onto the root state.

Answer (score 1):

> If I want to log my actions to a database or localStorage so that I can replay them to get to a consistent app state then even if rootState.timer.isRunning is true, my timer object will not be running.

I think that this is actually correct by design. When you reproduce a recorded log, you want everything to happen *exactly as it happened before* in terms of the produced actions.

For example, rather than fire off the real AJAX requests from your computer, while replaying actions, you’ll probably want to replay the recorded AJAX responses that were dispatched during that user session in the past.

I think timer falls into the same category: from the Redux point of view, action history *describes* what happened “as a result” of side effects, and replaying the actions should be enough to get your app into the same state even if those side effects did not actually fire again.

> The conditional if (!getState().timer.isRunning) requires that I know where in the root state timer is mounted. Since I'm building this as a library, I can't assume that timer is always going to be mounted directly onto the root state.

If you’re building a library, you also probably shouldn’t depend on the thunk middleware being available. It seems like you depend on it in your action creator. It is hard to say more without understanding your exact use case.